# Mercurial on share host without SSH

Tags: mercurial, hgsubversion

I am trying to get mercurial to work on a shared host without SSH access.

I have looked through https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories and seen different means to publish my repository to the web but not been able to get any method to work because of certain dependencies.

For example, I looked at hgweb, it says

"First of all, you need to have a Python installation that can access the mercurial package. Verify this by running python and typing the following:

import mercurial"

I havent worked with python before and as such not sure where to run the "import mercurial" command. i am guessing via ssh for which i do not have access.

Also came across SCM-Manager, the quick guide just talks about downloading the source and extracting the content to your server, SCM manager depends on java and also not sure how to get that to work over the web.

Which of hgweb, SCM-Manager and RhodeCode is possible to set up without ssh access?

Comment: I always ask this when I see the (many, many) shared hosting questions, "Why?"  You can get a t1 server from Amazon for free for a year.  It's plenty powerful and you have full control/root.  Why is everyone on these awful, no-root, shared environments that have them spending more time trying to run development servers from homedirs than actually building software?  What am I missing?

Comment: @Ry4an - cost. It does matter. "Free ONLY for year"

Comment: Sure, and after that it's $14.40 per month, which is still cheaper than hostgator or whatever shared-hosting ghetto these folks are are picking.  I'm not trying to be combative, I'm honestly trying to figure out why I see so many folks going down the shared hosting route when an EC2 node is more powerful and cheaper.  Hostgator (the  one about which I'm most often asked) is $15.90 / mo.

Comment: @Ry4an - because hosting (ordinary web-hosting) also was and is used for, well, ordinary web-hosting. 10 sites costs me, f.e, 7.00 EUR/mo

Comment: @LazyBadger there's no need to be flip -- I'm trying to learn.  7 EUR is $224 for two years, and an ec2 node is $168 for two years.  I still don't get they why of that decision.

Comment: @Ry4an - maybe ec2 isn't good choice for *somehow-popular* sites and as result OP will get this way $224 **and** $168 (I never used ec2)???

Comment: @LazyBadger maybe it isn't a good choice, but I don't know so that's why I'm asking.  If *anyone* who picks the shared hosting sites over ec2 to get less access for more money will explain to me why they did it, I'll be quite happy to have my curiosity sated.

Comment: @Ry4an - "The Right Tools for The Right Things" - webhosting **is** better for webhosting, SCM-hosting **is** better for hosting repo. I prefer do **not mix** two natures in order to get 2 good results instead of both with ornery quality

Comment: @LazyBadger that's still not actually a reason; that's a platitude.  _Why_ is that particular service offering better?  The bandwidth and uptime are worse for every service I've seen (especially when looking at hostgator), and they cost more .  I'm looking for an actual "I made this choice because of X" reason from someone who has made that choice.  The OP isn't chiming in so I'll ask in a more general forum, but I've yet to hear anyone say "I looked at ec2 and hostgator and picked hostgator because it does Y better."

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: **NONE**

But you can at least try, if you have Java Application Server running (Tomcat, GlassFish etc), run SCM-manager as Web application (*.war)